Identify a movie about a colony in isolated island
I'd like to know this movie title. I remember some of the plot. But, I still can not figure out the title of the movie.
The plot:
There are a group of people in an isolated island. I think they are criminals. In the island there are no technology. I think the island is not a prison. But, it's some kind of facility to see if the colony able to live without technology. There are people watching them (I'd call it "guard"). There is also a guard mingle with the colony as a Shaman.
In another scene, I remember the main guy is crying in front of giant campfire. I think he remember about the war where he bombs/kills people. There is also a scene where this guy fight another guy in some kind of pool. He wins by stabbing the guy with a wooden spear. There's another scene about the main guy is that is trying to go outside the island by boat. But, the guard shoot the boat woith some kind of laser from a futuristic aircraft. I think the guards somehow controls the wave too (not sure). 
The main guy is pretty famous. I remember seeing his face in another movies as well. But, I do not know his name. 
The movies is probably 90's. Its graphic is kind of old. It's in English.

No Escape 1994

A soldier convicted for murdering his commanding officer is dumped and left to die on a prison island inhabited by two camps of convicts.






Robbins is imprisoned for life for murdering his commanding officer, who in 2011 ordered him to kill scores of innocent men, women and children.
He is then forced to fight Casey, who secretly tailed Robbins to the camp but was caught in a booby trap. Casey impales and kills himself on Robbin's weapon.
The Insiders have secretly built a scan-proof boat and launch it, manned by secret volunteers to escape the island and tell the outside world about Absolom. However, somehow the boat is detected by the attack helicopter.



This looks like it. So, the island is a prison after all. My memory tricks me oh well.
